# Outlook 2010 add in not deploying properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment, outlook, add-in

I've googled this for two days and haven't come up with a solution.  I've created an Outlook 2010 Add-In (let's call it MyAddIn) using VS2010 and VSTO 4, and targeting .NET 4.0.  I'm using a setup project for deployment.
   What happens is that the installation seems to go OK.  The correct registry entries are created and all files are in the right place.  BUT, the Add In does not appear either in the Active, Inactive or Disabled lists in Outlook, and thus never runs when it's supposed to.

My setup package includes:

```
Microsoft .NET Framework
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll
Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.v4.0.Utilities.dll
MyAddIn.dll.manifest
MyAddIn.vsto
MyAddIn.dll (Primary Output)
```

Registry entries are as follows:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyCompany.MyAddIn\Description = "MyAddIn"
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyCompany.MyAddIn\FriendlyName = "MyAddIn"
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyCompany.MyAddIn\LoadBehavior = 3
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\MyCompany.MyAddIn\Manifest = "[TARGETDIR]MyAddIn.vsto|vstolocal"
```

Also, prerequisites in the add-in project are:

```
Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)
Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Tools for Office Runtime (x86 and x64)
```

I'm developing and deploying to Windows XP.  Both XP and MS Office 2010 have the very latest updates.  Any ideas??

Thanks.

One other thing...  If I go to Outlook's COM Add-Ins window and try to add my add-in manually, I get the following error:  [MyAddIn] is not a valid Office Add-In.   ???